# upload image to multiple models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave and Minimagick gem to upload an attachment to S3. Now I want to save the some.pdf in two models(ie, assignment, and message). I give the same parameters in attachment field to save in two tables. But the second table attachment saves blurry. First one gets clear view of attachment.
My controller codes like,

```
@assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
@message = Message.new
begin
  Message.transaction do
    asign_att = params[:assignment][:attachment]
    @assignment.save!

    @message.attachment = asign_att
    @message.save!
  end
end
```

My model has,

```
(in attachment.rb) mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
(in message.rb) mount_uploader :attachment, ImageUploader
```

I want to save same file into two models with clear view. What I want to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your second table uploader file if you have specified any version or something like that.
With version you can create clones of attachment in different resolutions like this.

```
 version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit 50, 50
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a callback to do this, something like:

```
after_commit :assign_to_models

def assign_to_models
  ...
end
```

IMHO, I would create an model that has all the carrierwave attachements, and have it belongs both to `message` and `attachement`.

I hope this helps